# How to create alias for template type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, template-aliases

I have some template classes whose declaration looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename A, typename B, typename C>
class foo1;

template <typename T, typename A, typename B, typename C>
class foo2;

...
```

I use them in the following context (every `foo*` is instantiated with `A` and `B` and `C` which `bar` was instantiated with)
 :

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class bar {
    foo1<int, A, B, C> f1;
    foo2<int, A, B, C> f2;
    foo2<char, A, B, C> f3;
};
```

For simplicity and clarity reasons I would like to be able to omit `A`, `B` and `C` parameters inside `bar` and just write:

```
...
foo1<int> f1;
...
```

I know that I could just use alias template for all `foo` types like this:

```
template <typename T>
using foo1_a = foo1<T, A, B, C>;
```

but there could be a lot for `foo` types and it would require creating alias for all of them.

I tried to put all this aliases in a class:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class types {
    template <typename T>
    using foo1_a = foo1<T, A, B, C>;

    ...
};
```

and then usage looks like this:

```
...
using t = types<A,B,C>;
typename t::template foo1_a<int> f1;
...
```

but in my opinion this looks even worse...

Is it possible to achieve this in some other way?

Comment: I know this is not "elegant", but you still have #define macro option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about

```
template <template <typename...> class Cnt, typename T>
using bar = Cnt<T, A, B, C>;
```

used

```
bar<foo1, int> f1;
bar<foo2, int> f2;
bar<foo2, char> f3;
```

?

Answer (score 2):

If `A` `B` `C` are only supplied into `bar` to be forwarded into `fooN` parameters then it may be worth to pack them. This way there will be no need to update bar signature if `fooN` signatures change.

```
template <typename… x_FooParams>
class bar {
    foo1<int, x_FooParams...> f1;
    foo2<int, x_FooParams...> f2;
    foo2<char, x_FooParams...> f3;
};
```